# Tensorflow libcublas.so.9.0 error - CUDA Version 10.0

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I cannot get around the problem regarding the configuration of tensorflow, here it is as follows:

```
(venv) home@home:~/Downloads/venv$ python models/research/object_detection/inputs_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/home/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/home/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/home/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/home/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/home/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
**ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

~/.bashrc has been modified as follows (last lines of code):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

and libraries tensorflow/models/research/ and slim directories have been appended to PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Any idea?

Comment: if you did a pip install tensorflow-gpu, then your using a version of tensorflow built for cuda9.0. If you want a version built with cuda 10.0, you'll need to build it yourself and find it from another location.

Comment: Thank you for tipping me off. Unfortunately after installing cuda9.0, I get in trouble with the import error "ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

By running ./deviceQuery I understand that: "deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 10.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.0, NumDevs = 1 Result = PASS" my CUDA is still 10.0 but the runtime is 9.0. Any idea on how to change it?

Comment: The new error, "ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", can be resolved by installing cudnn and running ldconfig. Download it from https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn. I think the cuda runtime version 9.0 is good.